# calculate using google spreadsheet, using what is in a column to get a value from another sheet

Tags: google-docs

I need to use a character-based field to obtain a number from a different sheet to be used in a sum with a column from the first sheet.

I have a sheet in google spreadsheet that has the columns: 
`Vets`, `number of males`, and  `cost`.

I need to have a SUM that will multiply `Vets` * `number of males` to provide `cost`.
BUT the info in `vets` will be character-based - i.e. Jones, for vet's names - and in another sheet I have a list of vets with the next column having a cost - i.e. 36.77.

I then want to take what is in the `cost` column of the 2nd sheet and multiply it with the column `number of males` in the first sheet to give me `cost` in the first sheet.

Any ideas?!

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-do-i-lookup-a-value-from-another-sheet-in-google-docs

Comment: Googled in seconds.  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: so do i need a new column in both sheets with a numeric value for each of the different vet names?            error i am getting is 'Not a number: Jones'

Comment: ok, got a little further... i am now getting the error: Parse error.. my string is =VLOOKUP(B2,LookupValue,costs!2)

Comment: ok, vlookup is one way, but I think Serpentine's method is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This [FAQ](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/75943?hl=en) explains how to reference cells from other sheets:

> Within a single spreadsheet, you can replicate data and copy it from one sheet to another by entering the sheet name and an exclamation mark before the cell being copied. Here are some examples:
>
> =Sheet1!A1
>
> ='Sheet number two'!B4

Is this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As0kdQoNo_pzdHdCWVJnbGtnZEZRNmJpdFUtVks1OHc&usp=sharing) something like what you're looking for?

Comment: the problem is that data will be added to the 1st spreadsheet daily and for each entry the vets names could be 1 of 20 different vets, which needs to be looked up in the 2nd spreadsheet and the cost in column 2 placed in the 1st spreadsheet. this is to avoid the person having to know the different costs for each vets, they only have to know the name of the vets. therefore cannot hardcode a sheetname&cell to be copied